# Python PandasD merge rows with equal index to be equal to 0 if every row has 0 in a column and 1 if any (or multiple) rows have a 1 in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am running a program in which I end up with a pandas DataFrame resembling:

| index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| ABC | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| DEF | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| DEF | 1 | 0 | 0 |

My desired transformation is:

| index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| DEF | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I have been trying to fix this using the groupby function as I have done for similar issues in the past, but I cannot figure out how to have the ABC example return 1. If there is an easier way to do this, I would also love to hear it. I have the DataFrame originally as a TSV file, so the DataFrame approach is not necessary.

Comment: take max of the group: `df.groupby('index',as_index=False).max()` should do

Comment: @anky Thanks! Where can I find a list of the functions that work with groupby? At the moment, I'm only aware of sum() (and now max())

Comment: You can refer the docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Group the dataframe by `index` (pass `level=0` if `index` is index column of the dataframe), then call `sum` to get the  sum of the values in each groups, finally create Boolean for `value>=1`, and convert it to integer type

```py
df.groupby('index').sum().ge(1).astype(int).reset_index()
  index  A  B  C
0   ABC  1  1  0
1   DEF  1  0  1
```